# SKU search not always working

Tags: magento-1.8, search, sku, search-terms

I have an issue where depending on the SKU it depends on what comes back.

I have 2 products

1. SKU - AFB
2. SKU - TUR

If I search for AFB it the search results only show that 1 product. If I search for TUR the results show 200 results and the product with the SKU of TUR is on page 3.

Is there a way to rank the product Higher as it directly matches the SKU

Screenshots of my settings are below

[image: Search settings]
[image: Attribute seetinsg]

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: no.

I would suggest searching for a module that offers advanced search. Or take a look at an alternative search engine like Elastic Search, Spinx or SOLR